# C# webAPI cannot bind original integer value to model from the body?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, webapi

My problem is when I send any integer value starting with zero (012345) in the payload body to C# web API the received value not having the first digit(12345). it is ignoring zero. how to force API to receive raw data?

```
[HttpPost]
    public void insertdata([FromBody]Model model)
    {
     // model.id=1234    
    }
```

payload

```
{id:01234}
```

Comment: an integer does not have leading zeros, use a string

Comment: @LukaszBalazy [FromBody] doesn't help

Comment: You will have to use string property for the same  instead of int to have leading zero

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An integer cannot have leading zeros as mentioned by @Richard in the comments

You should use string instead in your model.

```
public class YourModel {
   public string id {get;set;}
}

[HttpPost]
public void insertdata(YourModel model)
{
   model.id="01234";    
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think it depends on the DataType of the id property in your model object.

If id was a string, like, leading zeros as in 01234 will be preserved. Provided you are requirement is not particularly constraining you to make the `id` property an `int`

```
public class Model 
{

public string id { get; set;}
...

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Send any integer value  as a string "012345" - payload {id:"01234"}. Another way to reach it is to use string.PadLeft -  model.Id.ToString(),PadLeft(5,"0");

Answer (score 1):

[image: Poc visual studio c# console]

Good morning mate,

Follow the example I did in a POC, there are some problems in doing so that is when someone sending an id greater than 5 can give error in searching or causing duplication, the ideal was for them to send in string format. More so as long as the id is between 5 characters this solution will work.

Reference:

https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings

https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings#DFormatString